# Geometric distribution not quite right

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> The number of positive ions crossing a detector in a certain time
> until the first negative ion is seen is a random variable with $E(x) =
>  11$. Each cross is an independent event. The distribution function is
> given by $F_X (X \leq x) = 1 - (1-p)^x$ with $x = 1, 2, 3, ...$.
>
> What is the value of $p$? What is the probability of 4 consecutive positive ions
> crossings until you see the first negative ion crossing?

I believe this is a (binomial) geometric distribution with $X =$ "*number of positive ions crossing a detector in a certain time until the first negative ion is seen*" and for wich $E(X) = \frac{1}{p} = 11 \iff p = \frac{1}{11} = .090$.

Now that I have $p$ I believe that I may have to calculate $F(X \geq 5)$ but then I do $$F_X(X \geq x) = 1- F_X(X \leq x) = 1 -(1-(1-p)^x) = (1-p)^x = (1-.090)^5 = .624$$ this doesn't seem quite right to me because it is too high. Am I thinking something wrong here?

Comment: It is not high at all. Informally speaking, think about a random variable that is equal to $11$ "on average". Then it should be quite common that it is larger than $5$. On another note, it is up to interpretation whether you should compute $P(X\ge 5)$ or $P(X\ge 4)$.

Comment: @bugly I've made an additional Remark.

Comment: @callculus42 : you are fully right. I amended my answer

Comment: @tommik Although the comment wasn´t  addressed to you directly, I appreciate that you've made an edit. I don´t know how you've noticed my comment (so fast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, even the correct calculation (see @callculus latest remark) should be $P(X\ge 5)=(1-0.090)^4$. Your distribution is a geometric, not a binomial, with support $x=1.2.3,\dots$.

> What is the probability of 4 consecutive positive ions crossings until you see the first negative ion crossing?

if the question was

> What is the probability of **exactly** 4 consecutive positive ions crossings until you see the first negative ion crossing?

the answer was lower:

$$\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^4\cdot \frac{1}{11}=6.21\%$$

Answer (score 2):

> What is the probability of 4 consecutive positive ions crossings until
> you see the first negative ion crossing

This probability you can calculate with the $\textrm{pmf}$, not cdf. The $\textrm{pmf}$ is

$$f_X(k)=(1-p)^{k-1}\cdot p, \ \  \forall \  k\in \{1,2,3,...\}$$

So you need the probability for $k=5$.

**Remark** $(\textrm{11/9/2021})$

$F_X(X \geq x) = 1- F_X(X \leq x)$ is not right, since $X$ is a $\underline{\color{green}{\textrm{discrete}}}$ random variable. In this case we have

$$F_X(X \geq x) = 1- F_X(X < x)=1- F_X(X \leq x-1)$$

Comment: sorry but I think your interpretation is the probability of "exactly" 4 failures before the first success...

Comment: @tommik 4 failures are exactly 4 failures as 2 apples are exactly 2 apples. My view on the problem. Also: If the first success (s) comes after four failures (f), then you have a unique sequence: $\textrm{ffffs}$